# Chrome doesn't display text anymore

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Since a few days/weeks, I remarked that my website doesn't work properly on Google Chrome.

Every text disappeared, leaving a space, and when I hover my mouse over the text, it displays back.

Here's a screen:

http://puu.sh/7hOIY.png

I hovered the two first buttons, the text is displaying.

My website works fine on every other browsers. Only Google Chrome doesn't work, but my website worked a few days back, I didn't change anything.

I've seen that some says it may come from the fact that I'm using google fonts, but I don't see why and how I could fix it...

Comment: I doubt there's much anyone can do without seeing the HTML and what's not working..

Comment: Provide some code for the font or at least provide the site in question so people can investigate

Comment: Link, please. Probably you will need to update google fonts link - to add all possible variations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use custom fonts try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

 $(function() { $('body').hide().show(); });
</script>
```

Read more here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/elw8busIfJA

It's a chrome bug

Comment: Make sure you comment that code; it's confusing and anyone looking at that later is going to wonder what the heck it's for. An additional link to the chrome bug would be perfect.